# C#8.0: Protected properties for interfaces with default implementations

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

Say I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IReturnableAs {
  protected String ReturnAs { get; set; }
}
public interface IReturnableAsImage<T> {
  protected String ImageResolution { get; set; }
  public T ReturnAsImage(String imageResolution = "large") {
    ReturnAs = "image";
    ImageResolution = imageResolution;
    return (T)this;
  }
}
public interface IReturnableAsJson<T> {
  protected Boolean IsPretty { get; set; }
  public T ReturnAsJson(Boolean isPretty = false) {
    ReturnAs = "json";
    IsPretty = isPretty;
    return (T)this;
  }
}

public class Foo : IReturnableAsImage<Foo>, IReturnableAsJson<Foo> {...}
```

Initially, the errors force me to have implementations for the `ReturnAs`, `ImageResolution` and `IsPretty` properties. Making these implementations `protected` end up with `CS0535`, saying that the properties weren't implemented. On the other hand, making these `public` gave me `CS8704`, telling that this implementation is not possible.

Other than abstract classes, would there be workarounds for these errors?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `IReturnableAsImage<T> : IReturnable { … }` ? Because there is no `ReturnAs` property in `IReturnableAsImage<T>` which could be accessed in `ReturnAsImage`.

Comment: What do you expect `Foo.ReturnAs` to return? `json`, `image` or `json;image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what do you want to achieve? What should `Foo.ReturnAs` return? How are you going to use those interfaces?

You can't use `ReturnAs` in the other interfaces without inheriting from `IReturnableAs`. Once you inherit from that interface though `Foo` will have to provide an implementation. When that happens, no matter how you cast `Foo` you'll always get its own `IReturnableAs` implementation.

Interfaces aren't abstract classes so there can only be *one* interface member implementation. You can't access different "default" implementations through different interfaces.

**Composite result when accessed through IReturnableAs**

If you want to return `json` or `image` for the specific interfaces and `image;json` for `Foo` overall the best option would be for the interfaces to *not* inherit from `IReturnableAs`, and provide their own `ReturnAs` property :

```
public interface IReturnableAs {
  public String ReturnAs { get; }
}
public interface IReturnableAsImage<T>
{
  public String ReturnAs =>"image";

  protected String ImageResolution { get; set; }    
  public T ReturnAsImage(String imageResolution = "large") 
  {
    ImageResolution = imageResolution;
    return (T)this;
  }
}
public interface IReturnableAsJson<T> {
  public String ReturnAs =>"json";

  protected Boolean IsPretty { get; set; }
  public T ReturnAsJson(Boolean isPretty = false) {
    IsPretty = isPretty;
    return (T)this;
  }
}

public class Foo : IReturnableAsImage<Foo>, IReturnableAsJson<Foo> ,IReturnableAs
{
    string IReturnableAs.ReturnAs =>"image;json";

    String IReturnableAsImage<Foo>.ImageResolution { get; set; }="3";
    Boolean IReturnableAsJson<Foo>.IsPretty { get; set; }=false;
}
```

The following code :

```
void Main()
{
  var foo=new Foo();
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAs)foo).ReturnAs);
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsImage<Foo>)foo).ReturnAs);
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsJson<Foo>)foo).ReturnAs); 
}
```

Prints:

```
image;json
image
json
```

I removed the `ReturnAs` setters since the valid value will always be the same for the same interface.

If you want to create a new class that generates JPGs, eg `FooJpg`, you can override the default implementation of `IReturnableAsImage<T>`, eg :

```
public class FooJpg : IReturnableAsImage<FooJpg>, IReturnableAsJson<FooJpg> ,IReturnableAs
{
    string IReturnableAs.ReturnAs =>"jpg;json";

    String IReturnableAsImage<FooJpg>.ImageResolution { get; set; }="3";
    Boolean IReturnableAsJson<FooJpg>.IsPretty { get; set; }=false;

    String IReturnableAsImage<FooJpg>.ReturnAs => "jpg";

}
```

**Same result no matter the interface**

If you want `Foo.ReturnAs` to always return the same value, eg `"image;json"`, you can add a default `IReturnAs` implementation for single use cases, and override the method for multiple uses :

```
public interface IReturnableAs {
  public String ReturnAs { get; }
}

public interface IReturnableAsImage<T>:IReturnableAs
{
  String IReturnableAs.ReturnAs =>"image";

  protected String ImageResolution { get; set; }    
  public T ReturnAsImage(String imageResolution = "large") 
  {    
    ImageResolution = imageResolution;
    return (T)this;
  }
}

public interface IReturnableAsJson<T>:IReturnableAs { 
  String IReturnableAs.ReturnAs =>"json";

  protected Boolean IsPretty { get; set; }
  public T ReturnAsJson(Boolean isPretty = false) {
    //ReturnAs="json";
    IsPretty = isPretty;
    return (T)this;
  }
}
```

In this case the `IReturnableAsImage`, `IReturnableAsJson` interfaces provide an implementation. For this class :

```
public class Foo : IReturnableAsImage<Foo>
{
    String IReturnableAsImage<Foo>.ImageResolution { get; set; }="3";
}
```

The following code will print `image`:

```
void Main()
{
  var foo=new Foo();
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAs)foo).ReturnAs);
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsImage<Foo>)foo).ReturnAs);
}
```

For a class that uses both interfaces, an explicit `IReturnableAs` implementation is needed:

```
public class FooMulti : IReturnableAsImage<FooMulti>, IReturnableAsJson<FooMulti> 
{
    String IReturnableAs.ReturnAs =>"image;json";

    String IReturnableAsImage<FooMulti>.ImageResolution { get; set; }="3";
    Boolean IReturnableAsJson<FooMulti>.IsPretty { get; set; }=false;
}
```

In this case all calls will return `image;json` :

```
void Main()
{
  var foo=new FooMulti();
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAs)foo).ReturnAs);
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsImage<FooMulti>)foo).ReturnAs);
  Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsJson<FooMulti>)foo).ReturnAs); 
}

image;json
image;json
image;json
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution here, though I am not sure if I like it.

`IReturnableAsImage<T>` and `IReturnableAsJson<T>` can extend `IReturnableAs` and hide its `ReturnAs` method with a `new` `ReturnAs` method.

They can, and probably should, also explicitly override `IReturnableAs`'s `ReturnAs` property to save a concreate implementation from having to do so; see the implementation of `Bar` below.

Since `Foo` implements both `IReturnableAsImage<T>` and `IReturnableAsJson<T>` though, it will have to provide an implementation for `IReturnableAs.ReturnAs` as well.

```c#
public interface IReturnableAs
{
    public String ReturnAs { get; }
}

public interface IReturnableAsImage<T> : IReturnableAs
{
    // implicitly "override" IReturnableAs's ReturnAs
    string IReturnableAs.ReturnAs => ReturnAs; 
    
    // use "new" to indicate hiding on purpose
    public new string ReturnAs => "image"; 

    protected string ImageResolution { get; set; }

    public T ReturnAsImage(String imageResolution = "large")
    {
        ImageResolution = imageResolution;
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public interface IReturnableAsJson<T> : IReturnableAs
{
    // implicitly "override" IReturnableAs's ReturnAs
    string IReturnableAs.ReturnAs => ReturnAs;

    // use "new" to indicate hiding on purpose
    public new string ReturnAs => "json";

    protected bool IsPretty { get; set; }

    public T ReturnAsJson(Boolean isPretty = false)
    {
        isPretty = isPretty;
        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

`Bar` doesn't need to implement `IReturnableAs.ReturnAs` as `IReturnableAsImage<Bar>` already does this. Though it may to "overload" (reimplement may be a better term) `ReturnAs` implicitly or either `IReturnableAs.ReturnAs` or `IReturnableAsImage<Bar>.ReturnAs` explicitly, in any combination.

```c#
public class Bar : IReturnableAsImage<Bar>
{
 // public string ReturnAs => "implicit ReturnAs";
 // string IReturnableAs.ReturnAs => "explicit IReturnableAs.ReturnAs";
 // string IReturnableAsImage<Bar>.ReturnAs => "explicit IReturnableAsImage<Bar>.ReturnAs";

    string IReturnableAsImage<Bar>.ImageResolution { get; set; } = "3";
}
```

`Foo` on the other hand must explicitly reimplement `IReturnableAs.ReturnAs` implicitly or `ReturnAs` explicitly (or both) since both IReturnableAsImage and IReturnableAsJson provide implementations for this property.

```c#
public class Foo : IReturnableAsImage<Foo>, IReturnableAsJson<Foo>
{
 // public string ReturnAs => "implicit";
 // string IReturnableAsImage<Bar>.ReturnAs => "explicit image";
 // string IReturnableAsJson<Bar>.ReturnAs => "explicit json";

    string IReturnableAs.ReturnAs => "image;json";

    string IReturnableAsImage<Foo>.ImageResolution { get; set; } = "3";
    bool IReturnableAsJson<Foo>.IsPretty { get; set; } = false;
}
```

The results work as expected, though changing what the concrete methods reimplement will change the results, possibly unexpectedly.

```c#
void Main()
{
    var bar = new Bar();
    Console.WriteLine("Bar: ");
    Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAs)bar).ReturnAs + " -  (IReturnableAs)" );
    Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsImage<Bar>)bar).ReturnAs + " - 
 (IReturnableAsImage<Bar>)");

    // only works when ReturnAs is explicitly implemented on Bar
 // Console.WriteLine(bar.ReturnAs + " -  (Bar)"); 

    Console.WriteLine();

    var foo = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo:");
    Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAs)foo).ReturnAs + " -  (IReturnableAs)");
    Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsImage<Foo>)foo).ReturnAs + " -  (IReturnableAsImage<Foo>)");
    Console.WriteLine(((IReturnableAsJson<Foo>)foo).ReturnAs + " -  (IReturnableAsJson<Foo>)");

    // only works when ReturnAs is explicitly implemented on Foo 
 // Console.WriteLine(foo.ReturnAs + " -  (Foo)");  
     }
```

Output:

```
Bar:
image -  (IReturnableAs)
image -  (IReturnableAsImage<Bar>)

Foo:
image;json -  (IReturnableAs)
image -  (IReturnableAsImage<Foo>)
json -  (IReturnableAsJson<Foo>)
```

You may want to comment in the commented out lines of `Foo` and `Bar` above to see what gets overloaded and when.

For example, if `Bar` explicitly implements `ReturnAs` it overrides default implementations of both `IReturnableAs` and `IReturnableAsImage<Bar>` unless `Bar` implicitly implements them as well.